# change the background image in gallery

Tags: android, background, gallery

i shows a buttons in gallery view for scrolling purpose. if i clicked one button(ex:button1) then change the button1 background and then i clicked another button(ex:button2) then change the background of the button2 and also get the previous background of the button1. So please tell me how to change the background in gallery.

Best Regards.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Gallery.setSelection(int position, boolean animation);

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.but it is for seletion but i  want to change the background

Answer (score 1):

[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class has a [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) method. I suppose that this is what you are looking for.